# How to get effected rows number widh PDO fetchColumn()?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, pdo

When i updatind DB

```
$sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE....
$sql -> execute(array(....
```

i would like know are my db been updated or no? how to get row amount?

```
$row_count = $sql -> fetchColumn();
```

this work only with select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[rowCount()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)**

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.

You can do

```
echo $sql->rowCount();
```

**Note**

`fetchColumn()` has nothing to do with `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements and won't work here like you expect. That only works if you have data returned in the result set, using `SELECT` mostly.